# Webpack config SVGO

Tags: svg, webpack

i need to check name in SVG file for further processing. How to write correct test expression ? Is this right ?

```
test: /[Multicolored]\.svg$/,
```

if file is named

```
 "iconCall.Multicolored.svg"
```

?

Can / Should i use same loader with different test expression ? For svgs tagged with `Multicolored` i need to remove some attributes for others i don´t. This is my basic config for remove attrs:

```
  {
test: /\.svg$/,
include: SRC,
use: [
  {
    loader: 'svg-sprite-loader',
  },
  {
    loader: 'svgo-loader',
    options: {
      plugins: [
        { removeNonInheritableGroupAttrs: true },
        { collapseGroups: true },
      ],
    },
  },
],
```

},

Answer (score 0):

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) you can see that

> [Multicolored] will match any one of the characters in the brackets.

So, for your purpose you should use /^Multicolored.svg$/ regular expression.